# Extracting data from XML in R

Tags: r, xml

I need to extract certain data from XML that looks like this (simplified for brevity)

```
<Doc name="Doc1">
    <Lists Count="1">
        <List Name="List1">
            <Points Count="3">
                <Point Id="1">
                    <Tags Count ="1">"a"</Tags>
                    <Point Position="1"  /> 
                </Point>
                <Point Id="2">
                    <Point Position="2"  /> 
                </Point>
                <Point Id="3">
                    <Tags Count="1">"c"</Tags>
                    <Point Position="3"  /> 
                </Point>
            </Points>
        </List>
    </Lists>
</Doc>
```

The output should be a data frame that matches a tag and position to each point Id

```
    Point  Tag Position
1     1    a        1
2     2 <NA>        2
3     3    c        3
```

I am new to XML, I was playing with xml2 package. So far, I could extract each variable separately, but since some points may not have a Tag data , I can't find a way to match between the three parameters.

```
> library(xml2)
> xml_data<-read_xml(...)
> xml_data %>% xml_find_all("//Point") %>% xml_attr("Id")
[1] "1" "2" "3"
> xml_data %>% xml_find_all("//Vertical") %>% xml_attr("Position")
[1] "1" "2" "3"
> xml_data %>% xml_find_all("//Tags") %>% xml_text()
[1] "\"a\"" "\"c\""
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`purrr` and `xml2` go well together:

```
library(xml2)
library(purrr)

txt <- '<Doc name="Doc1">
    <Lists Count="1">
        <List Name="List1">
            <Points Count="3">
                <Point Id="1">
                    <Tags Count ="1">"a"</Tags>
                    <Point Position="1"  /> 
                </Point>
                <Point Id="2">
                    <Point Position="2"  /> 
                </Point>
                <Point Id="3">
                    <Tags Count="1">"c"</Tags>
                    <Point Position="3"  /> 
                </Point>
            </Points>
        </List>
    </Lists>
</Doc>'

doc <- read_xml(txt)
xml_find_all(doc, ".//Points/Point") %>% 
  map_df(function(x) {
    list(
      Point=xml_attr(x, "Id"),
      Tag=xml_find_first(x, ".//Tags") %>%  xml_text() %>%  gsub('^"|"$', "", .),
      Position=xml_find_first(x, ".//Point") %>% xml_attr("Position")
    )
  })
## # A tibble: 3 × 3
##   Point   Tag Position
##   <chr> <chr>    <chr>
## 1     1     a        1
## 2     2  <NA>        2
## 3     3     c        3
```

Answer (score 1):

Run `xpathApply` over the `//Points/Point` nodes and for each such node `x` get the `Id`, the `Tag` (or NA if none) and the `Position`:

```
library(XML)

doc <- xmlTreeParse(Lines, asText = TRUE, useInternalNodes = TRUE)

do.call("rbind", xpathApply(doc, "//Points/Point", function(x) 
  data.frame(Id = as.numeric(xmlAttrs(x)[["Id"]]), 
             Tags = c(gsub('"', '', xmlValue(x[["Tags"]])), NA)[[1]],
             Position = as.numeric(xmlAttrs(x[["Point"]])[["Position"]],
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE))))
```

giving:

```
  Id Tags Position
1  1    a        1
2  2 <NA>        2
3  3    c        3
```

**variation**

A variation on the above giving the same answer is this.  At each `Point` node it creates a string of the attributes and values and then uses `read.table` to read it in:

```
library(XML)

doc <- xmlTreeParse(Lines, asText = TRUE, useInternalNodes = TRUE)

xp <- xpathSApply(doc, "//Points/Point", function(x) paste(
        xmlAttrs(x)[["Id"]],  
        c(gsub('"', '', xmlValue(x[["Tags"]])), NA)[[1]], 
        xmlAttrs(x[["Point"]])[["Position"]]))
read.table(text = xp, col.names = c("Id", "Tags", "Position"), as.is = TRUE)
```

**Note:** Input `Lines` is:

```
Lines <- '<Doc name="Doc1">
    <Lists Count="1">
        <List Name="List1">
            <Points Count="3">
                <Point Id="1">
                    <Tags Count ="1">"a"</Tags>
                    <Point Position="1"  /> 
                </Point>
                <Point Id="2">
                    <Point Position="2"  /> 
                </Point>
                <Point Id="3">
                    <Tags Count="1">"c"</Tags>
                    <Point Position="3"  /> 
                </Point>
            </Points>
        </List>
    </Lists>
</Doc>'
```